# Remove first occurrence of item

Tags: php, string, list

I have a comma separated list, and would like to remove the first occurrence of `1` from the list, but also removing any extra commas that were separating that value. How would this be done?

This is the string:

```
 $str = '1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10';
```

I need to replace the first `1` so it looks like this:

```
$str = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10';
```

I need to remove the extra commas, because the numbers are linked to the items that display on the page in MySQL DB.

Comment: Can you show a real world example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$search = 1;
$items = explode(',', $csvString);
if (($index = array_search($search, $items)) !== false)
  unset($items[$index]);
$csvString = implode(',', $items);
```

Comment: You don't handle the case where 1 isn't in the array. Edit: You have edited your answer.

Comment: @Hammerite: I don't know, when you write this comment, but I do: Thats the stuff with the `if`-thing. Edit: Yes :)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I can't accept the answer for 3 more minutes, but I'll accept it then.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex to remove 1 and any neighboring ,'s

```
$result = preg_replace('/(,|^)1(,|$)/', '$2', $subject, 1);
```

It should be faster than exploding/imploding